# Why won't my text in a Love2D game update?

Tags: text, lua, love2d

I finally fixed the problem regarding the text not showing up in my game, now the next problem was it won't update. What was supposed to happen is that when I press the up and down arrow keys, the selected text would change, then pressing Enter would bring me to a new state, or quitting the game.

The code in my `StartState.lua` now looks like this:

```
StartState = Class{__includes = BaseState}

local option = 1

function StartState:update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.wasPressed('up') then
        if option == 1 then
            option = 2
        else
            option = 1
        end
    elseif love.keyboard.wasPressed('down') then
        if option == 2 then
            option = 1
        else
            option = 2
        end
    end

    if love.keyboard.wasPressed('enter') then
        if option == 1 then
            gStateMachine:change('play')
        else
            gStateMachine:change('quit')
        end
    end
end

function StartState:render()
    local backgroundWidth = gTextures['start-background']:getWidth()
    local backgroundHeight = gTextures['start-background']:getHeight()

    love.graphics.draw(gTextures['start-background'], 0, 0, 0, VIRTUAL_WIDTH / (backgroundWidth - 1), 
        VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / (backgroundHeight - 1))

    love.graphics.setFont(gFonts['large'])
    love.graphics.setColor(153/255, 217/255, 234/255, 255/255)
    love.graphics.printf('Attack Them All', 0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2 - 50, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')

    love.graphics.setFont(gFonts['medium'])
    love.graphics.setColor(0/255, 0/255, 0/255, 255/255)
    love.graphics.printf('Play', 0, (VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2) + 2, VIRTUAL_WIDTH + 2, 'center')
    love.graphics.printf('Quit', 0, (VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2) + 22, VIRTUAL_WIDTH + 2, 'center')

    if option == 1 then
        love.graphics.setColor(255/255, 174/255, 201/255, 255/255)
        love.graphics.printf('Play', 0, (VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2), VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
        love.graphics.setColor(237/255, 28/255, 36/255, 255/255)
        love.graphics.printf('Quit', 0, (VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2) + 20, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
    else
        love.graphics.setColor(237/255, 28/255, 36/255, 255/255)
        love.graphics.printf('Play', 0, (VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2), VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
        love.graphics.setColor(255/255, 174/255, 201/255, 255/255)
        love.graphics.printf('Quit', 0, (VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2) + 20, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
    end

    love.graphics.setColor(255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 255/255)
end
```

I already added up a `StateMachine` on my `main.lua` file:

```
function love.load()
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter('nearest', 'nearest')

    math.randomseed(os.time())

    love.window.setTitle('Attack Them All')
    
    push:setupScreen(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, {
        vsync = true,
        fullscreen = false,
        resizable = true
    })
    
    gStateMachine = StateMachine {
        ['start'] = function() return StartState() end,
        ['play'] = function() return PlayState() end,
        ['quit'] = function() return QuitState() end
    }
    
    gStateMachine:change('start')
end

function love.update(dt)
    gStateMachine:update(dt)
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try taking a look at `love.keyboard.wasPressed()` to see any problems, but if not there, pay attention to the option number.

Answer (score 0):

love.keyboard.wasPressed is not a standard Love2D API. Should be implemented somewhere else in your code? Check this first.
Then try to put some `print("condition xxx is verified")` in your conditions where your code is supposed to be executed, then you'll find where the condition is not verified.

Example:

```
if love.keyboard.wasPressed('up') then
   print("up is pressed")
   ...
```

Comment: Actually, I made the `love.keyboard.wasPressed()` function but I didn't include it in the question.